# Which candidate from kurento is use for ReceiveCandidate in client?

Tags: webrtc, kurento

I usec# IceLink for develop webrtc,When I sent json "operation":"gatherCandidates" to kurento

The Kurento answer many candidate to me like this::

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:1 1 UDP 2013266431 fe80::5054:ff:fef2:132e 58277 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio0"},"source":"5f0f76e9-270d-46e4-b93f-a04f0f98591b_kurento.MediaPipeline/b5af38f9-2696-4352-9965-f9af01caf055_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1475555352","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"5f0f76e9-270d-46e4-b93f-a04f0f98591b_kurento.MediaPipeline/b5af38f9-2696-4352-9965-f9af01caf055_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:2 1 TCP 1019217151 fe80::5054:ff:fef2:132e 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio0"},"source":"5f0f76e9-270d-46e4-b93f-a04f0f98591b_kurento.MediaPipeline/b5af38f9-2696-4352-9965-f9af01caf055_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1475555352","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"5f0f76e9-270d-46e4-b93f-a04f0f98591b_kurento.MediaPipeline/b5af38f9-2696-4352-9965-f9af01caf055_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:3 1 TCP 1015022847 fe80::5054:ff:fef2:132e 49390 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio0"},"source":"5f0f76e9-270d-46e4-b93f-a04f0f98591b_kurento.MediaPipeline/b5af38f9-2696-4352-9965-f9af01caf055_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1475555352","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"5f0f76e9-270d-46e4-b93f-a04f0f98591b_kurento.MediaPipeline/b5af38f9-2696-4352-9965-f9af01caf055_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:4 1 UDP 2013266431 202.44.12.183 55877 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio0"},"source":"5f0f76e9-270d-46e4-b93f-a04f0f98591b_kurento.MediaPipeline/b5af38f9-2696-4352-9965-f9af01caf055_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1475555352","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"5f0f76e9-270d-46e4-b93f-a04f0f98591b_kurento.MediaPipeline/b5af38f9-2696-4352-9965-f9af01caf055_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:5 1 TCP 1019216383 202.44.12.183 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio0"},"source":"5f0f76e9-270d-46e4-b93f-a04f0f98591b_kurento.MediaPipeline/b5af38f9-2696-4352-9965-f9af01caf055_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1475555352","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"5f0f76e9-270d-46e4-b93f-a04f0f98591b_kurento.MediaPipeline/b5af38f9-2696-4352-9965-f9af01caf055_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:6 1 TCP 1015022079 202.44.12.183 54635 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio0"},"source":"5f0f76e9-270d-46e4-b93f-a04f0f98591b_kurento.MediaPipeline/b5af38f9-2696-4352-9965-f9af01caf055_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1475555352","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"5f0f76e9-270d-46e4-b93f-a04f0f98591b_kurento.MediaPipeline/b5af38f9-2696-4352-9965-f9af01caf055_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:1 2 UDP 2013266430 fe80::5054:ff:fef2:132e 55435 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio0"},"source":"5f0f76e9-270d-46e4-b93f-a04f0f98591b_kurento.MediaPipeline/b5af38f9-2696-4352-9965-f9af01caf055_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1475555352","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"5f0f76e9-270d-46e4-b93f-a04f0f98591b_kurento.MediaPipeline/b5af38f9-2696-4352-9965-f9af01caf055_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:2 2 TCP 1019217150 fe80::5054:ff:fef2:132e 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio0"},"source":"5f0f76e9-270d-46e4-b93f-a04f0f98591b_kurento.MediaPipeline/b5af38f9-2696-4352-9965-f9af01caf055_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1475555352","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"5f0f76e9-270d-46e4-b93f-a04f0f98591b_kurento.MediaPipeline/b5af38f9-2696-4352-9965-f9af01caf055_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:3 2 TCP 1015022846 fe80::5054:ff:fef2:132e 49448 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio0"},"source":"5f0f76e9-270d-46e4-b93f-a04f0f98591b_kurento.MediaPipeline/b5af38f9-2696-4352-9965-f9af01caf055_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1475555352","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"5f0f76e9-270d-46e4-b93f-a04f0f98591b_kurento.MediaPipeline/b5af38f9-2696-4352-9965-f9af01caf055_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:2 2 TCP 1019217150 fe80::5054:ff:fef2:132e 9 typ host tcptype active","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio0"},"source":"5f0f76e9-270d-46e4-b93f-a04f0f98591b_kurento.MediaPipeline/b5af38f9-2696-4352-9965-f9af01caf055_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1475555352","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"5f0f76e9-270d-46e4-b93f-a04f0f98591b_kurento.MediaPipeline/b5af38f9-2696-4352-9965-f9af01caf055_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:4 2 UDP 2013266430 202.44.12.183 52003 typ host","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio0"},"source":"5f0f76e9-270d-46e4-b93f-a04f0f98591b_kurento.MediaPipeline/b5af38f9-2696-4352-9965-f9af01caf055_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1475555352","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"5f0f76e9-270d-46e4-b93f-a04f0f98591b_kurento.MediaPipeline/b5af38f9-2696-4352-9965-f9af01caf055_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"onEvent","params":{"value":{"data":{"candidate":{"__module__":"kurento","__type__":"IceCandidate","candidate":"candidate:6 2 TCP 1015022078 202.44.12.183 44986 typ host tcptype passive","sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"audio0"},"source":"5f0f76e9-270d-46e4-b93f-a04f0f98591b_kurento.MediaPipeline/b5af38f9-2696-4352-9965-f9af01caf055_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","tags":[],"timestamp":"1475555352","type":"OnIceCandidate"},"object":"5f0f76e9-270d-46e4-b93f-a04f0f98591b_kurento.MediaPipeline/b5af38f9-2696-4352-9965-f9af01caf055_kurento.WebRtcEndpoint","type":"OnIceCandidate"}}}
.
.
.
{"id":6,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"sessionId":"5b12b64d-192a-4545-9812-16223ef3820f","value":null}}
```

It has both of  TCP and UDP.

My Question is

1.which candidate to use for ReceiveCandidate in client. TCP or UDP if use TCP it's use typ host tcptype active or passive?

2.Or my client recieve all candidate from kurento?

thankyou fr advance,

Answer (score 0):

During the WebRTC connection establishment, each peer sends a set of ICE candidates to the remote peer. Those candidates can be UDP, TCP, srflx (STUN), host or relay (TURN). When the remote peer receives the candidates, it starts probing those IPs and ports to see if a connection can be established. That's why each peer sends a number of them, so the remote peer has more chances of finding a valid candidate.

If you want to know which candidate pair is being used, you can subscribe to [NewCandidatePairSelectedEvent](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_static/langdoc/javadoc/org/kurento/client/NewCandidatePairSelectedEvent.html) from your [WebRTC](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_static/langdoc/javadoc/org/kurento/client/WebRtcEndpoint.html#addNewCandidatePairSelectedListener(org.kurento.client.EventListener)).

Comment: thank you  that mean,Should I accept of all set of ICE candidate?

Comment: @jojoth You don't need to accept any particular candidate, the peers will do that.